# Getting the characters of a string up to the first "."

Tags: string, perl, split

I'm attempting to use Perl's `gethostnamebyaddr` function.  The annoying thing is that it returns the entire domain name in scalar format. I want to parse out only the hostname and discard the rest.

I'm using `split` to divide the domain name into an array and then taking only the first value but this doesn't seem to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Socket;

my $name;
my $hostname;
my @tmpStr;

$name  = gethostbyaddr(inet_aton("192.168.2.3"), AF_INET);
print "$name\n";

@tmpStr = split ".", $name;
$hostname = $tmpStr[0];
print "Host name is $hostname\n";
```

When the above code is executed, I get the following:

```
dc1-ent.ent.ped.local 
Host name is
```

According to [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_gethostbyaddr.htm) website the return value is not a string but is rather a scalar value and so my attempt at splitting it doesn't work.

I can't figure out how to convert it to a string before I can split it or parse out the hostname by itself.

Comment: A string is a scalar value...

Comment: This shows my limited knowledge of perl.  I've spent most of my programming (still not much) in VB.  Thanks for the clarification Patrick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dot character has special meaning for regular expressions in Perl, and the 1st argument to [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) is a regular expression.  You need to escape the dot:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $name = 'dc1-ent.ent.ped.local';
print "$name\n";
my @tmpStr = split /\./, $name;
my $hostname = $tmpStr[0];
print "Host name is $hostname\n";
```

This outputs:

```
dc1-ent.ent.ped.local
Host name is dc1-ent
```

Answer (score 2):

I would write it like this

```
my $name = gethostbyaddr(inet_aton('192.168.2.3'), AF_INET);
my ($host) = $name =~ /([^.]+)/;

say $host;
```

Comment: To get the *first* characters up to the first `.` I would suggest using `/^([^.]*)/`:

Comment: @memowe: Why? You think it might skip a few characters without the anchor? Especially with a `*` quantifier, which will happily match nothing at all if `$name` starts with a dot! `gethostbyaddr` can not return strings like that.

Comment: Matching the empty string shouldn't be considered a problem when the empty string is "the characters of a string up to the first dot". There's no difference regarding `gethostbyaddr` and the regex with anchor matches correctly in the general case.

Comment: @memowe: You've added an anchor and changed the quantifier. I'm happy with the quantifier, although making a change purely because it does no harm (*"shouldn't be considered a problem"*) is very odd, but you need to answer why you think the anchor is an improvement. Is it just that it also does no harm?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not related to `gethostbyaddr()` but by what follows.

Proof:

```
 DB<1> $name = 'dc1-ent.ent.ped.local';

 DB<2> @tmpStr = split ".", $name;

 DB<3> print @tmpStr;
```

(nothing printed)

Try instead using `split` that way:

```
  DB<8> $name = 'dc1-ent.ent.ped.local';

  DB<9> @tmpStr = split(/\./, $name);

  DB<10> print @tmpStr;
dc1-ententpedlocal
  DB<11> print join(' ', @tmpStr);
dc1-ent ent ped local
  DB<12> x @tmpStr;
0  'dc1-ent'
1  'ent'
2  'ped'
3  'local'
```

Or if you absolutely want a string and not a regex, protect the dot also as your string is still parsed as a regular expression (which is why being explicit with `/  /` has its merits, it forces you to remember that some character have special meaning there, like the dot):

```
  DB<1> $name = 'dc1-ent.ent.ped.local';

  DB<2> @tmpStr = split('.', $name);

  DB<3> print @tmpStr;

  DB<4> @tmpStr = split('\.', $name);

  DB<5> x @tmpStr
0  'dc1-ent'
1  'ent'
2  'ped'
3  'local'
```